# Double slashes close together with resizing

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols, kerning

I basically want [this symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126711/double-slash-close-together), but I want it to resize properly: While

```
X/\mkern-6mu/H
```

looks good, when I try to resize using `\biggl`, then the horizontal space between the two slashes becomes very large:

```
\biggl.X\biggl/\mkern-6mu\biggl/H\biggr.
```

Is there any solution to this? None of the suggestions in the original question resize properly.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: By using `biggl/` you are making `/` big. Corresponding spacing also will increase. Adjust `\mkern` value accordingly. But why should you use `biggl/`, I don't understand.

Comment: You should use `\big`, not `\bigl`. Also `\biggl.` and `\biggr.` are completely useless.

Comment: Picture a situation where `X` and `H` are replaced by something much larger. I do not see why `biggl` and `biggr` are completely useless. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain What do you think `\biggl.` is doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `\biggl.` and `\biggr.` do exactly nothing, except introduce unwanted opening and closing atoms (and, possibly, the relative spacing).

Second, `\bigl/` makes the bigger `/` an opening atom, so you should use `\big`, instead.

Third, the bigger `/` has wider sidebearings than the normal size symbol. If you need it only at normal and `\big` size, here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\dslash}{s}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\big/\mkern-7mu\big/}
    {/\mkern-6mu/}%
}

\begin{document}
$X\dslash H$

$X\dslash* H$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want other sizes, then something more complex should be devised. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dslash}{O{}}
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {}{/\mkern-6mu/}
    {\big}{\big/\mkern-7mu\big/}
    {\Big}{\Big/\mkern-10mu\Big/}
    {\bigg}{\bigg/\mkern-14mu\bigg/}
    {\Bigg}{\Bigg/\mkern-18mu\Bigg/}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$X\dslash H$

$X\dslash[\big] H$

$X\dslash[\Big] H$

$X\dslash[\bigg] H$

$X\dslash[\Bigg] H$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, thanks. This is very help- *and* insightful. I have one more question, though: Is there any way to make this work with `\left.` and `\right.`, in the sense that the `\dslash` is resized automatically?

Comment: Actually, I think that [this is a whole different question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161969/create-a-resizable-symbol), so I made it one.