# How to make a delimiter out of a character, eg \right!, similar to \right)

Tags: tex-core

I must be missing something simple but could not find  \right| and was wondering how to duplicate a matching vertical bar after a formula.

Edit

My mistake! I forgot \left. .
But I guess one can ask the question for \right!. Not sure if it is of much use though.

[Related 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109699/how-can-i-create-a-new-extensible-symbol)

Comment: `\right|` is correct. If you want a *double* bar (for the norm), `\left\|` and `\right\|` are what you need.

Comment: @egreg My mistake! I edited the post.

Comment: Only "extensible" characters can be used after `\left` and `\right`; the extensibility is defined in the font metric file.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161969/create-a-resizable-symbol

Comment: Apart from those linked (and possible duplicates) answers… wouldn't it be possible to do it with Latex commands rather than changing the font definitions? I mean, —to me— it looks like the only thing needed is measure the height of a “*box*” and then compute some numbers and fill that height with some predefined symbols. May be not easy but seems possible… Am I missing something?